# How good is my computer aided diagnosis system vs the expert?

Tags: correlation, modeling, prediction, predictor

I have developed a systematic method that attempts to quantify the amount of disease present in medical images. E.g. % area abnormal.

In my dataset, I have healthy people with no disease, and people with various degrees of disease presentation. An expert has graded the disease for each person in the dataset as Normal (=0), Mild (=1), Moderate (=2), and Severe (=3).

Each person in the dataset is scanned in different body areas (6 slices in total) in one session, such that I have 6x '% area abnormal' quantities for every person. But the expert has graded them on a per person basis.

**Question 1:** What statistical tests may be appropriate, to tell me how well my system correlates with the expert's opinion? E.g., using SPSS or Matlab.

It is not entirely clear how to handle the 6x samples per person: Either to use them as separate entities, combine to get an average, or perhaps take the maximum of the 6. Ideally, the test would allow to try these options.

Afterwards, the system will be tested on out-of-sample data.

Please see below for some example data:

```
Patient1, Region1: 10.22%, Graded as Normal
Patient1, Region2:  8.81%, Graded as Normal
Patient1, Region3:  7.77%, Graded as Normal
Patient1, Region4:  8.56%, Graded as Normal
Patient1, Region5:  8.60%, Graded as Normal
Patient1, Region6:  9.26%, Graded as Normal
Patient2, Region1: 12.23%, Graded as Mild
Patient2, Region2: 12.40%, Graded as Mild
Patient2, Region3: 14.02%, Graded as Mild
Patient2, Region4: 11.22%, Graded as Mild
Patient2, Region5: 11.96%, Graded as Mild
Patient2, Region6: 12.23%, Graded as Mild
```

**Question 2:** If multiple experts are used, what statistical tests may be appropriate?

Comment: I have no answer but I like this problem. I have two (related) questions : How many patients are in your dataset ? Is it possible that some regions are more critical than others, in this case would a weighted sum a reasonable choice ?

Comment: 30 people in the dataset. 20 people reserved for out-of-sample testing. (The disease prevalence is extremely low so its difficult to scan them.) The disease, although systemic, can occur in patches in any region. Thanks for your interest!